# Why does the Command prompt and PowerShell give different output results than the Terminal?

Tags: linux, powershell, cmd.exe, cygwin, linux-terminal

I have the following example code from a book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello World (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
  int rc = fork();

  if (rc < 0)
  {
    //fork failed
    fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  else if (rc == 0)
  {
    //child (new process)
    printf("Hello I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
  }

  else
  {
    //parent goes down this path (main)
    printf("Hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
            rc, (int) getpid());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In Windows (powershell and command prompt) I get the following:

```
Hello World (pid:1283)
Hello, I am parent of 1284 (pid:1283)Hello I am child (pid:1284)
```

In Linux (terminal) I get:

```
Hello World (pid:1923)
Hello, I am parent of 1924 (pid:1923)
Hello I am child (pid:1924)
```

As shown in the following images.

why does the same code display differently in different programs?
Is Windows just incorrectly displaying the output based on how it reads code? Or is it something with its compiler? I use the included gcc on Linux. I use cygwin gcc on Windows.

#### PowerShell on Windows

[image: powershell-windows]

#### Terminal on Linux

[image: terminal-linux]

#### Command Prompt on Windows

[image: cmd-windows]

Also running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Name\n");
    printf("Address Line 1\n");
    printf("Address Line 2");
}
```

Prints the code correctly in PowerShell on Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Cygwin there is a **apparently a race condition** where it outputs the chars forming the body of the line and then the line-ending (`CRLF`), and another process is able to get in between so you actually get `body1 body2 CRLF CRLF` (spacing added for clarity).

Standard C prohibits stdout to an 'interactive device' to be fully buffered (i.e. more than one line), but allows less, and in any case how the operating system (which C officially calls the 'host environment') handles output from multiple processes once 'transmitted' to it is entirely outside the scope of C — and even POSIX for this case if I’m not mistaken — not that Cygwin could fully satisfy POSIX anyway.

Comment: This answer is great! Thanks for the clarification on Cygwin stuff.

Answer (score 1):

## You are using a Unix newline (`\n`) on Windows where it should be `\r\n`.

Differences well [explained here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s06.html):

> There are three different types of line breaks, all originally unique to the major operating systems: Windows/DOS, Macintosh, and Unix. A document using Mac line breaks would look horrid on a Windows system, and a document using Windows line breaks on Unix also wouldn’t be interpreted correctly. The cause for this is how the line break is actually created. The Mac, by default, uses a single carriage return (`<CR>`), represented as `\r`. Unix, on the other hand, uses a single linefeed (`<LF>`), `\n`. Windows goes one step further and uses both, creating a () combination, `\r\n`.

To test for yourself, just change these lines:

```
printf("Hello World (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
printf("Hello I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
printf("Hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
            rc, (int) getpid());
```

To this:

```
printf("Hello World (pid:%d)\r\n", (int) getpid());
fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\r\n");
printf("Hello I am child (pid:%d)\r\n", (int) getpid());
printf("Hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\r\n",
            rc, (int) getpid());
```

If there is a desire for cross-platform consistency with line breaks, I would recommend simply applying a constant to your code based on OS/shell version that would assign the correct line break and then assign that to all the places you have `\n` in your code.

Comment: I understand. But why does this not affect Java code? Using the newline without carriage return works in Windows. Why is this? Also other C code I wrote using the newline operator only works like it has the `\r` without me needing to type it.

Comment: @Jinzu You don’t mention Java in your original question so that is out of the scope of this question. But honestly, I am not 100% sure why but Java was originally written as a cross-platform WORA (write once, run anywhere) language that meant that if you wrote Java code on Windows, and I then run it on a Mac or Linux machine, the output would be uniform. I would recommend you start a new question about Java — if you wish — that references this question and answer thread and someone with more Java knowledge than me can answer.

Comment: I updated the question. I have some code on my machine written in the C language that doesn't need the `\r\n` to be written. I asked the question because this is the first time I coded with C that did not give a carriage return and newline when I only type `\n`.

Comment: **C runtime handles this for you** unless you use a defective implementation of C, or override by `fopen` with mode `b` which Q doesn't; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255198/escape-sequence-for-a-true-linefeed-lf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages . And it wouldn't explain the result in the Q anyway, which does have the correct 'nextline' operations but in different order.